# How can I store a symbol in a Rails 4 model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I often need to store a constant. Symbols work well for defining constant types, but I don't know how to define them in a Rails model. I would create a separate model to store the types. For example, I have a `Game` model that has a `status` attribute.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :status
end
```

The `status` attribute is an association with another model called `Status`. The `status` table has four rows, each defining a different `status` and each `status` has a name attribute that's a string.

```
def change
  create_table :statuses do |t|
    t.belongs_to :game
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

but this feels inefficient and wrong. Ideally, I could have a column in `Game` table that stores a symbol/constant. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your game status can be thought of as an enumerated type. I like very much storing these as records in a separate database table. It makes them easy to rename and migrate while maintaining data integrity.

You may also want to try the "enum" feature which is new to Rails 4.1. You could simply declare something like the following

```
class Game
  enum :status => %w[Init Pause Play End]
end
```

Note that you would need to add a "status" column of type integer to support this.

For more try reading 
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/whats-new-in-edge-rails-active-record-enum
http://richonrails.com/articles/active-record-enums-in-ruby-on-rails-4-1

Answer (score 1):

I would create a set of constants to represent the range of possible statuses. These would be stored in the database as ints. Those ints can be compared against Game::Over for example in the code.

```
class Game
  NotStarted = 0
  InPlay     = 1
  Over       = 2

  ...
end

puts "let's get started!" if Game.find(id).status == Game::NotStarted
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems simple enough!

Comment: did that work? I was expecting `NOT_STARTED` and so on.

Comment: I would like an option where you have an array or hash, it tends to be useful that way